# Как разместить бота на хостинге под линуксом

Tags: python, linux, хостинг

Тестирую скрипт через администратора хостинга, где находится сайт клиентов сайт.

Когда применяю простой скрипт открытия файлов без библиотек, всё работает.
Но как только запускаю свой нормальный скрипт с библиотеками, то сразу возникает ошибка 500.

Банально в самом начале запинается на первой строке библиотеки

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from aiogram import Bot, types
```

Comment: Так ошибка должна писаться при запуске скрипта, если она есть